# How to apply a buildSrc plugin in settings.gradle

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a plugin file in `<root>/buildSrc/src/main/groovy/stuff/Stuff.groovy`:

```
class StuffPlugin implements Plugin<Settings> {
  @Override
  void apply(final Settings target) {
    target.gradle.ext.someVariable = 'foo'
  }
}
```

I want to do this in `settings.gradle`:

```
import stuff.StuffPlugin

apply plugin: StuffPlugin
```

But I get:

```
Could not compile settings file '<root>/settings.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  settings file '<root>/settings.gradle': 1: unable to resolve class stuff.StuffPlugin
   @ line 1, column 1.
     import stuff.StuffPlugin
     ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Apparently this is a classpath issue. If I dump the plugin class code directly into the settings.gradle file, it works as expected.